# top.location.pathname stopping jquery working on other pages

Tags: jquery

I have added the following statement above a plugin so that the plugin will only work only on specific pages.

```
if (top.location.pathname === '/' || top.location.pathname === '/Tickets/Sell/' || top.location.pathname === '/Contact/') {


!function ($) {
```

The problem is since I have added this statement my Jquery will only work on the pages listed above.

i.e the following statement which is in the  on the master page will only run on the login page if the login URL is added to the plugin statement.

```
           <script>
           $(function () {
               if  (location.href.match('Login/?Redirect=/Basket/')) {
                   $('div#sign').show();
               }
               else {
                   $('div#sign').hide();
               }
           });
                   </script>
```

Any help / Advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you added these if cases top of the plugin.
You have to care about where did you added 
if you are using post-back way then it works but if you uses partial request(ajax) then script link may not work.(Browser do not download the js file).
I guess question can be more specific.

Questions :

Where did you added that plugin js?
Which request method are you using?

Comment: I added the if statement above a plugin file to act as a filter so its not requesting anything, its just allowing the JQuery to only work on the pages specified.

Comment: Maybe you can handle that situation like this.

add plugin into pages that is displayed on the browser window. You don't need to use if case

Comment: Just remove <script src="context"> from head and put it into body of pages that you want to use